# nginx uwsgi upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a python `flask` application which outputs around `300kb` for a request.

This application is hosted via `uwsgi emperor` with the below configuration.

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /var/www/%n

socket = /etc/uwsgi/sockets/%n.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vaccum = true

processes = 4
threads = 20

virtualenv = /var/www/%n/.venv
module = app:app
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
```

The `uwsgi` log has the below line

```
[pid: 16668|app: 0|req: 1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {46 vars in 700 bytes} [Wed May  2 04:56:24 2018] POST /context-path => generated 293595 bytes in 34172 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 75 bytes (3 switches on core 0)
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
```

And the `nginx` configuration is

```
location /context-path {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/etc/uwsgi/sockets/app.sock;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

At the end of 5 minutes, I see the following in `nginx` `error.log`

```
2018/05/02 05:13:42 [error] 16994#16994: *7 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "POST /context-path HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/etc/uwsgi/sockets/app.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

I receive partial data at the end of 5 minutes.
Increasing `uwsgi_read_timeout` doesn't affect anything.

Help?

Stack configuration:

1. nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
2. uwsgi 2.0.17
3. Python 2.7.12
4. Flask==0.12.2

Comment: Hi, Did you solve this issue. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Not sure but I think it was the problem with my application code in which multiprocessing is mismanaged

Comment: Thanks Mouli, for your response. I shifted  to Apache.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this error message can occur with many of the different upstream options.

The ngx_http_upstream_module module is used to define groups of servers that can be referenced by the proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, scgi_pass, memcached_pass, and grpc_pass directives.

I am using nginx as a load balancer with other servers, using proxy_pass. So I needed one of the proxy_* timeout options, such as proxy_read_timeout, to fix this error.